Why Measure method doen't work in Colab?
I'm a beginner in Qiskit. When I use Statevector and then measure method in Colab as follows
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
n=Statevector([(1+2.0j)/3,-2/3])
n.measure

it returns this message
qiskit.quantum_info.states.quantum_state.QuantumState.measure
def measure(qargs: list | None=None) -> tuple
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/quantum_info/states/quantum_state.py
Measure subsystems and return outcome and post-measure state.

Note that this function uses the QuantumStates internal random
number generator for sampling the measurement outcome. The RNG
seed can be set using the :meth:`seed` method.


Args:
    qargs (list or None): subsystems to sample measurements for,
                          if None sample measurement of all
                          subsystems (Default: None).

Returns:
    tuple: the pair ``(outcome, state)`` where ``outcome`` is the
           measurement outcome string label, and ``state`` is the
           collapsed post-measurement state for the corresponding
           outcome.

that I don't understand. I appreciate any help.

Statevector.measure() is a class method in python, so to execute the function you need to add parenthesis at the end:
n.measure()


Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot.
